# Pressure relief valve on well pressure tank

Tags: plumbing

Hi I m changing out my 33 gal pressure tank to a 44 gal.  Instructions say I need a pressure relief valve but I don’t have one on original set up so my shallow jet pump pressure switch is set at 20/40. Should I install a pressure relief valve?

Comment: Have almost the same setup as you, no relief valve.  Did have the pressure switch stick on(did not turn off) once and the pressure went close to 100 pounds.  A pressure relief valve is cheap insurance.

Comment: @crip659 How did you know the switch stuck on? I assume the water came out of the faucets at an alarming rate, but I've never seen this before and as a new person to having a well I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Hi yes sir cheap insurance, it never occurred to me I will install one now  thanks guys !!!

Comment: @RetiredATC  It only happen once in 40 years.  Pressure was high at the faucets and developed a few leaks at pipe joints.  Having a spare pressure switch comes in handy, since they wear out.

Comment: @crip659 Could you please explain how a pressure regulator would fit into the water system? Would it be mounted just after the tank? Is there a way that you could tell that the well pressure switch was stuck open if you had a pressure regulator?

Comment: @RetiredATC   Would imagine to add a tee near the outlet(into the house pipes) of the tank.  It is a pressure relief valve(same on hot water tanks), not a pressure regulator valve.  Most water tanks have a pressure gauge on/near them

Comment: @crip659 OK. That makes sense. My well is set at 30-50. What size (lbs) pressure relief valve would you recommend?

Comment: Water pipe joints/connections(common house type) tend to get wonky after 80 pounds.  I would guess you don't something over 100/120 pounds, but probably will need something a bit less than the tank itself is rated for, which should be much higher.

Comment: You can put the pressure relief valve anywhere it is convenient however there is one cravat there CANNOT be a valve between it and the pump.

Comment: Wow I have had wells and pressure tanks most of my life built homes and remodeled and never seen a pressure relief on a well only a TPR on the hot water tank. I guess I might be concerned if the well pump had a high end over 100psi but water is not a compressible like air so if a failure it will be a leak not an explosion like a compressed air tank.

Answer (score 1):

A pressure relief valve is required to protect from a condition where the pressure switch fails to shut the pump off. It should be of a value well above the normal pressure in the house, and well below the pressure rating of the tank - the tank folks require one because when the pressure tank is over-pressurized, it becomes an explosion hazard. Under normal operation conditions, it should never actuate. It's not **for** normal operating conditions. It's a safety device for abnormal conditions.

Most domestic systems operate at 80 PSI or below, and most tanks are rated for more than 100 PSI, so a 100PSI relief valve is fairly commonly available. With a 40 PSI cut out you could use a lower pressure relief valve, like 75 PSI, but one might be *somewhat* more difficult (certainly not impossible) to find. So long as your tank is rated for MORE than the relief valve, it will do the important job.

Depending on your particular pump you might handwave about the pump not being able to pump that high (if it can't) but the valve is cheap insurance, and if the pump got replaced with a different one...

Comment: Water is not an explosion hazard this is why they use water to test pressure tanks to aprox 5/3 working pressure for hydrostatic testing. If they split the pressure is gone because water is not a compressible like air.

Comment: @EdBeal A well pressure tank is air over water, and the **air** is the part that makes "explosion" a problem here, same as it is for an air compressor tank.

Comment: It is a fixed bladder of limited volume the pressure set at or within 2 psi of the low pressure cut in let’s get crazy and put it at 80 still at max compression 120 there is only 120 psi of air how many well pumps can produce more than that water pressure ? small volume pressure tanks don’t even require hydrostatic testing (under 2” in diameter) even at high pressures +2000 psi so I don’t see a real explosion issue. And yes I have had tanks rust and split they just peed.